# Spring - Java Map HashMap to Multi-Layer Pojo

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, pojo

I have a hash map `Map<String, String>` that has following value, please note that the dot indicates the hierarchy:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|    Key             |  Value    |
+--------------------+-----------+
| car.color          | blue      |
| car.engine.make    | mitsubishi|
| car.engine.power   | 120       |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

I have pojo classes:

```
public class Vehicle {

    private Car car;
   **Setters and Getters Below*  
}    

public class Car {
    private String color;

    private Engine engine;
    **Setters and Getters Below*      
}

public class Engine {
    private String make;

    private Integer power;
    **Setters and Getters Below**
}
```

Is there any way i can map the HashMap into the POJO class based on the hierarchy? I tried to use jackson `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();` but it seems able to map 1 level of object.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid building up the object manually?

Comment: Yup i can do that by using switch case, and do like `case "car.engine.make" then set it in the object`, but the switch codes will become lengthy if i have alot of value in the map

Comment: No switch cases, you can just build the mapping class once, requesting directly by the strings and dumping them in the right places. It will most likely be the most efficient way to do it unless you're talking about over 200 strings in the map? On another note, wouldn't it be better to represent the data in something other than a hasmap to maintain the structure better to start off with or is this not possible?

Comment: For the mapping class, do you have any URLs i can refer to, like rough idea of how to do it? Yes it is not possible to change the data structure, it have to be like what i mentioned.

Comment: I'll add a quick solution I wrote up for this example as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`@JsonCreator` annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#using-constructors-or-factory-methods) on your `Vehicle` class' constructor:

```
@JsonCreator
public Vehicle(Map<String, String> map) {
    String color = map.get("car.color");
    String make = map.get("car.engine.make");
    Integer power = Integer.valueOf(map.get("car.engine.power"));
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    engine.setMake(make);
    engine.setPower(power);
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setColor(color);
    car.setEngine(engine);
    this.car = car;
}
```

Usage:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("car.color", "blue");
map.put("car.engine.make", "mitsubishi");
map.put("car.engine.power", "120");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Vehicle vehicle = mapper.convertValue(map, Vehicle.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to map the hashmap into POJO with `jackson`, you have to refactor the structure:

```
{
  "car": {
    "color": "blue",
    "engine": {
      "make": "mitsubishi",
      "power": 20
    }
  }
}
```

Or, you can parse the hashmap and construct each `class` manually.

Comment: Yeah i realized that too, but too bad i can't change the structure though

Comment: so you have to parse the hashmap and set values to color, engine one by one.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to use your classes:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class CarMap {

    Map<String, String> maap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public CarMap() {
        Car c = new Car("blue", new Engine("mitsubishi",120));

        maap.put("color", c.color);
        maap.put("make", c.engine.make);
        maap.put("power",Integer.toString(c.engine.power));

        Set<String> keys = maap.keySet();
        for (String el : keys) {
            System.out.println(el+"\t"+maap.get(el).toString());
        }

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        obj1.put("color",maap.get("color").toString());

        JSONArray engList = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        obj2.put("make",maap.get("make").toString());
        engList.add(obj2);

        JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject();
        obj3.put("power",maap.get("power").toString());
        engList.add(obj3);

        obj.put("car", obj1);
        obj.put("engine", engList);
        System.out.print(obj);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CarMap();
    }


    class Car {

        private String color;
        private Engine engine;

        Car(String c, Engine e) {
            this.color = c;
            this.engine = e;
        }
    }

    class Engine {

        private String make;
        private Integer power;

        Engine(String m, Integer p) {
            this.make = m;
            this.power = p;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
color   blue
power   120
make    mitsubishi
{"car":{"color":"blue"},"engine":[{"make":"mitsubishi"}, "power":"120"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to just get this done and out of the way while keeping it simple would be to map these manually as follows. You might want to consider null checking optional values as you go along.

```
Map<String, String> map = *population here*

Engine engine = new Engine()
engine.setMake(map.get("car.engine.make"))
engine.setPower(map.get("car.engine.power"))

Car car = new Car();
car.setColor(map.get("car.color");
car.setEngine(engine);

Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
vehicle.setCar(car);
```